# requests package python exception certificate error

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I am having an issue with the requests package and an exception. I catch the exception but the program still crashes. Is this because I need to catch the more specific exceptions that are occurring?

I do know why the SSL certificate is saying it isn't valid. I'm having a time synch issue. This is outside of this post! I am working on the time issue separately.

```
def getpublicIP():
    #get public IP through IPify.org
    for url in ['https://api.ipify.org']:
        try:
            ipaddress = requests.get(url, timeout=3).text
            logging.error(f'IP address successful')
            return ipaddress
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            logging.exception('Cannot get public IP')
            return 0
```

So my log returns 'Cannot get public IP' as it should and then the program crashes. This is in the log.

```
06/29/2020 03:28:26 PM - root - ERROR - Cannot get public IP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1056)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1056)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/BOB/mainBOB.py", line 365, in getpublicIP
    ipaddress = requests.get(url, timeout=3).text
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

Should I be catching the requests.exceptions.SSLError AND the urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError specifically outside of the connection error? Should I catch them both or just the first?

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch more research, I am going to test the exception in this way:

```
except requests.exceptions.SSLError as ssl_error:
```

I will report back to see if catching and handling the error this way avoids the crashing of the program.